# Pandas resample by Date and select 2nd smallest value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame that looks similar to

```
2020-01-07 09:00:00,22,228
2020-01-07 10:00:00,22,228
2020-01-07 11:00:00,22,228
2020-01-07 12:00:00,22,228
2020-01-07 13:00:00,22,228
2020-01-07 14:00:00,22,228
2020-01-07 15:00:00,21,228
2020-01-07 16:00:00,22,228
2020-01-08 09:00:00,43,45
2020-01-08 10:00:00,44,45
2020-01-08 11:00:00,41,45
2020-01-08 12:00:00,47,43
```

I would like to get the 2nd smallest value of each column by data.
I know I can get the minimum by doing `df = df.resample('D', on='DateTime').min()` and I am aware that `nsmallest(n=2)` and `last` could combine to get what I need.

How do I use the `resample` together with `nsmallest`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Resampler.aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) with custom function for return some value e.g. `NaN` if not exist second smallest val:

```
def f(x):
    v= x.nsmallest(2)
    try:
        return v.iat[1]
    except:
        return np.nan

df = df.resample('D', on='DateTime').agg(f)
```

If want second unique smallest value:

```
def f(x):
    v = np.sort(np.unique(x))
    try:
        return v[1]
    except:
        return np.nan
```

Comment: `nsmallest` requires  positional argument `columns`. How do I make it work against both non-datetime columns?